# Can anyone help me with proxy server set up in setting Dev Eco Environment?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am newly setting up Dev Eco on my Mac. Can anyone help me with the proxy server set up in setting Dev Eco Environment? Is it an important step for setting up my environment or can I skip it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are behind any **firewall/proxy-server/corporate network**, you will have to configure [proxy settings](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/environment_config-0000001052902427) in DevEco Studio. Otherwise no need to configure proxy settings. Try Accessing remote device from **Tools -> DeviceManager** or try **Gradle sync some third-party dependencies**. You should be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following the process below.

[image]

[image]

For details, you could refer to [this document](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/installation_process-0000001071425528) to set up the DevEco Studio development environment.